# Can someone explain the differences in decomposition rates for when two molecules which have 2 different substituents?

Tags: organic-chemistry, kinetics, radicals

Just having trouble on why these two have such different decomposition rates, I would like to think its because NO2 is electron withdrawing but I cannot see why this would change the rate...some please explain?[image: 2 molecules with different decomposition rates]

Comment: What is the decomposition pathway?

Comment: Would it first decompose at the O-O bond? then the C-C bond next to the C=O, is that correct?

Comment: Uhhuh, that seems pretty legitimate. So how would the NO2 group stabilise the radical that you form?

Comment: By withdrawing electrons away from the ring? I assume this would make rate decrease due to the radical becoming less able to react further on? I know that NO2 is an electron withdrawing group so this would occur where as in the methyl group, it is electron activating and thus would make the radical more unstable? thus increasing the decomposition rate